# "dbt run" get stuck while running

Tags: dbt

[image: image of console showing DBT not progressing past step 89 out of 118 steps]

'dbt run' get stuck, and when I check the running queries in the database, there's nothing. It suddenly stops without any error messages.

When I try to run each model alone using 'dbt run --select model' it works.

Please help

Comment: Hi -- welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is very broad and hard to answer. Can you please run `dbt --debug run` and include the last lines of the logs in your question? Also please mention what database/warehouse you are using and other helpful information about your project configuration and this problem (e.g., is this a new problem? what changed recently? How long does that model take to run on its own?)